# running xampp in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, permissions, php, xampp

I've installed xampp on my ubuntu 18.04. I am able to run new wordpress sites. 
However if i try to run my other wordpress sites from htdocs folder, it just downloads the folder but not serve me the site itself. 
I thought it is because of permissions therefore I've given chmod 777 -R folder_name. 
Still the problem exists. 
Xampp is serving me new sites properly. 
Help would be appreciated.